# vue : need a data table package that give summation of rows and column

Tags: vue.js, datatable, datagrid, nuxt.js

I need a data table package that give me the ability to make a data table like below picture .

I need that table to calculate summation of each column and row .

[image]

Comment: please, read [How do I ask...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service; please show what you'd already tried to solve the problem you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

You can either pick one of those here: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#table

Or use the table component of your CSS framework if you use one, Bootstrap, Buefy and a lot of others do have tables baked in already.